# Using Comparator.thenComparing for passed string

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, lambda, comparator

I'm using streams to try and create an arraylist of the keys in a map sorted first by the values (integers) then sort the keys alphabetically. I have them sorted by the values, but I get an error when trying to compare them alphabetically:

```java
 return map.keySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing( (k1) -> map.get(k1)).thenComparing(String::compareTo)) //ErrorHere
          .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Coc-java gives me a `The method thenComparing(Comparator<? super Object>) in the type Comparator<Object> is not applicable for the arguments (String::compareTo)` error. I have used thenComparing before, but the .sorted method looked like this:

```java
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo))
```

This produced no errors and worked fine. I'm supposing that it might have something to do with what the lamda returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to explicitly specify the type, e.g. `Comparator.comparing((String k1) -> map.get(k1))`, or `Comparator.<String, WhateverTheValueTypeIs>comparing(map::get)`.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem! Thanks a lot.